# Find subsequences of strings within strings

Tags: python

I want to make a function which checks a string for occurrences of other strings within them.
However, the sub-strings which are being checked may be interrupted within the main string by other letters.

For instance:

```
a = 'abcde'
b = 'ace'
c = 'acb'
```

The function in question should return as `b` being in `a`, but not `c`.

I've tried `set(a)`. intersection(set(b)) already, and my problem with that is that it returns `c` as being in `a`.

Comment: These type of strings are called [subsequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) of the longer string.

Comment: This question is a special case of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877249/find-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-subsequence-in-a-string The solutions there are much more efficient for solving this case as well.

Answer (score 11):

You can turn your expected sequence into a regex:

```
import re

def sequence_in(s1, s2):
    """Does `s1` appear in sequence in `s2`?"""
    pat = ".*".join(s1)
    if re.search(pat, s2):
        return True
    return False

# or, more compactly:
def sequence_in(s1, s2):
    """Does `s1` appear in sequence in `s2`?"""
    return bool(re.search(".*".join(s1), s2))

a = 'abcde' 
b = 'ace' 
c = 'acb'

assert sequence_in(b, a)
assert not sequence_in(c, a)
```

"ace" gets turned into the regex "a.*c.*e", which finds those three characters in sequence, with possible intervening characters.

Answer (score 5):

how about something like this...

```
def issubstr(substr, mystr, start_index=0):
    try:
        for letter in substr:
            start_index = mystr.index(letter, start_index) + 1
        return True
    except: return False
```

or...

```
def issubstr(substr, mystr, start_index=0):
    for letter in substr:
        start_index = mystr.find(letter, start_index) + 1
        if start_index == 0: return False
    return True
```

Comment: I expect this to run faster than the regex-based answer. Do you have timings?

Comment: Nope no timings, just wrote it as an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

```
def issubstr(s1, s2):
    return "".join(x for x in s2 if x in  s1) == s1

>>> issubstr('ace', 'abcde')
True

>>> issubstr('acb', 'abcde')
False
```

Comment: Explain the white space comment please.

Comment: The question was to find subsequence, not substring