# Dynamic Programming and Probability

Tags: algorithm

I've been staring at this problem for hours and I'm still as lost as I was at the beginning. It's been a while since I took discrete math or statistics so I tried watching some videos on youtube, but I couldn't find anything that would help me solve the problem in less than what seems to be exponential time. Any tips on how to approach the problem below would be very much appreciated!

> A certain species of fern thrives in lush rainy regions, where it typically rains almost every day.
>   However, a drought is expected over the next n days, and a team of botanists is concerned about
>   the survival of the species through the drought. Specifically, the team is convinced of the following
>   hypothesis: the fern population will survive if and only if it rains on at least n/2 days during the
>   n-day drought. In other words, for the species to survive there must be at least as many rainy days
>   as non-rainy days.
>   Local weather experts predict that the probability that it rains on a day i ∈ {1, . . . , n} is
>   p<sub>i</sub> ∈ [0, 1], and that these n random events are independent. Assuming both the botanists and
>   weather experts are correct, show how to compute the probability that the ferns survive the drought.
>   Your algorithm should run in time O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: It's pretty straight forward. The recursion for "will it rain more than n/2 days?" is "(probability that it rains today * probability that it will rain n/2-1 days of the remaining days) + (probability that it does not rain today * probability that it will rain n/2 days of the remaining days)". Clearly both branches in the computation have a lot of overlap. The dp matrix could for instance be set up so that DP[i][j] stores the probability of rain on i days for the remaining j days.

Comment: I think I'm starting to grasp it. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. I've also written an elaborate tutorial-like answer to another popular entry level DP question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6877313/276052) which you might find educational.

Answer (score 4):

Have an `(n + 1)`×`n` matrix such that `C[i][j]` denotes the probability that after `i`th day there will have been `j` rainy days (`i` runs from `1` to `n`, `j` runs from `0` to `n`).  Initialize:

- `C[1][0] = 1 - p[1]`
- `C[1][1] = p[1]`
- `C[1][j] = 0` for `j > 1`

Now loop over the days and set the values of the matrix like this:

- `C[i][0] = (1 - p[i]) * C[i-1][0]`
- `C[i][j] = (1 - p[i]) * C[i-1][j] + p[i] * C[i - 1][j - 1]` for `j > 0`

Finally, sum the values from `C[n][n/2]` to `C[n][n]` to get the probability of fern survival.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic programming problems can be solved in a top down or bottom up fashion.

You've already had the bottom up version described.  To do the top-down version, write a recursive function, then add a caching layer so you don't recompute any results that you already computed.  In pseudo-code:

```
cache = {}
function whatever(args)
    if args not in cache
        compute result
        cache[args] = result
    return cache[args]
```

This process is called "memoization" and many languages have ways of automatically memoizing things.

Here is a Python implementation of this specific example:

```
def prob_survival(daily_probabilities):
    days = len(daily_probabilities)
    days_needed = days / 2

    # An inner function to do the calculation.
    cached_odds = {}
    def prob_survival(day, rained):
        if days_needed <= rained:
            return 1.0
        elif days <= day:
            return 0.0
        elif (day, rained) not in cached_odds:
            p = daily_probabilities[day]
            p_a = p * prob_survival(day+1, rained+1)
            p_b = (1- p) * prob_survival(day+1, rained)
            cached_odds[(day, rained)] = p_a + p_b
        return cached_odds[(day, rained)]

    return prob_survival(0, 0)
```

And then you would call it as follows:

```
print(prob_survival([0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8])
```